# Android manifest VM minimal heap size

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, dalvik, heap-memory

Is there an option to declare the required minimal VM heap size for the OS/device in Android manifest, such that the Android Market would only display the application for devices meeting the requirement and filter out the rest.

I can detect the maximal VM heap size during the startup of the application, and fail if there is not enough available memory. However, this would be inconvenient for the users.

To be specific, I'm working on a hobby game with a friend, where graphics require at least 16MB but no more than 24MB of memory. The memory usage is more or less optimal in a sense that only required graphics are loaded in memory at any given state of the game.

Comment: No, I don't think there is something like that.

Comment: I was afraid there isn't as I did not find anything about that in the docs either. The best thing is then to try to reduce the amount/quality of the graphics in the game.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK, that is the only option you have.

Comment: +1: There's no way to do this, but this is still a useful question, because it helps us to confirm that there is no way to do it!

Answer (score 3):

One way which you could use to ensure that your application uses maximum of available heap is by setting **android:largeHeap=true** in manifest file of your application. But this feature is available for operating systems 3.0 and above